# Music not playing 50% of the time when loading scene

Tags: aframe

```
<a-assets>
            <audio id="Theme" src="Theme.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

</a-assets>

<a-entity position="0 0 -1" sound="src:#Theme;autoplay:true;loop:false" rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 1" visible="true"></a-entity>
```

My code seems correct, but only loads some of the time. What gives?

Comment: Check the browser console for errors.

Comment: I figured out a workaround. Works by changing from aframe ver 0.6.0 to 0.5.0. So idk what's wrong, but now it works 100% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why You got so many minuses, it really does not work as expected. 
You didn't explain what error You get, i get the:
 `TypeError: Failed to execute 'decodeAudioData' on 'BaseAudioContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'ArrayBuffer'`

My guess is aframe is trying to process the audio before it's loaded or smth, because removing the `preload = 'auto'` attribute solves the issue. Maybe the component bypasses some listeners when it's set to auto, I'm not sure. Anyway, when i get rid of the preload attribute its working as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/numbmqk2/2/

Comment: glad i could help :) feel free to check the anwser if You don't have any further questions :)